# Изменение стиля элемента с атрибутом data через Js

Tags: javascript

Как можно поменять стили элементов где есть атрибут data через JS?
Данный метод не сработал
Нужно именно с атрибутом data менять а не через class/id.

```
<button class="rNumbers" id="n36" data="red"></button>
<button class="rNumbers" id="n37" data="red"></button>

let test1 = document.querySelectorAll([data="red"]);
function test(){
    test1.style.opacity = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых Вы создаете функцию, но не где её не вызываете, поэтому она не выполняется, исправим это:

```
test();
```

Dо-вторых, пользовательские атрибуты следует писать через `data-name`:

```
<button class="rNumbers" id="n36" data-color="red">кнопка</button>
```

Подробнее про пользовательские атрибуты: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

В-третьих, чтобы вернуть элементы с data-color='red', нужно заключить это выражение в кавычки:

```
let test1 = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='red']");
```

Ну и самое главное - `querySelectorAll` возвращает NodeList, поэтому, чтобы применить стили к каждому элементу из этого NodeList, можно воспользоваться методом forEach:

```
test1.forEach(el => {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
});
```

Подробнее про querySelectorAll: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Подробнее про forEach: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Полный код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="rNumbers" id="n36" data-color="red">кнопка</button>
  <button class="rNumbers" id="n37" data-color="red">кнопка</button>
  <button class="rNumbers" id="n37" data-color="green">кнопка</button>

  <script>
    let test1 = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='red']");

    function test() {
      test1.forEach(el => {
        el.style.opacity = 0;
      });
    };

    test();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за такое развернутое и хорошее объяснение, вы мне очень помогли!